# Trying to understand why git creates a new branch after upstream git push

Tags: git

I am very new to git. Trying to figure some stuff out, so pls be gentle :-)

I'm trying to understand why git seems to create a new branch after an upstream git push.

starting sitation:

```
git checkout
```

says

```
FETCH_HEAD                      HEAD                            master                             pep-complaincy
```

then i do

```
git push --set-upstream pep8compliancy
```

and i get

```
FETCH_HEAD                      HEAD                            master                          pep8compliancy/pep-complaincy   pep-complaincy
```

They way I understand is that by doing the push command, I link my local "pep-complaincy" branch to a remote "pep8complaincy" branch.

I would expect the output of "git checkout" either to read "pep-complaincy" (not showing the remote branch) OR to read "pep8compliancy/pep-complaincy" (indicating that the local branch is now linked to a remote branch).

Can't figure out why git is now showing 2 branches.
Any help explaining this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use `git checkout`. It is an old, obsolete and [confusing command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) used to:

- switch branch (now replaced by [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch))
- restore files (now replaced with [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore))

Second, if you want to see the branches (local and remote) and their relationship, use:

```
git branch -avv
```

Comment: In fairness, neither `switch` nor `restore` seems to have *replaced* `checkout` yet; they are still documented as experimental. (This is distinct from `checkout` being deprecated but remaining along side stable `switch` and `restore` commands.)

Comment: @chepner I agree. Those commands are here to stay though, as confirmed last week: https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqq4kor6g8z.fsf@gitster.c.googlers.com/

Comment: Ah, I didn't mean to imply they could go away, only that their behavior wasn't yet set in stone. Definitely use `switch` and `restore` in interactive use, where you can adjust your behavior as necessary, but `checkout` would still seem to be preferred if you want stability in a tool that wraps `git`.

Answer (score 0):

```
git push --set-upstream pep8compliancy
```

This will create a relationship between your current local branch (which is `master`) and the upstream branch `pep8compliancy`, which should *probably* be called `pep8compliance` so as to not offend the grammar Nazis out there :-)

If you want a new branch with the same upstream name, that would have been something like:

```
git co master                            # Start with master as baseline.
git pull                                 # Ensure up to date.
git co -b pep8compliancy                 # New local branch at same point.
git push --set-upstream pep8compliancy   # Push to upstream, linking names.
```